# custom ListView item in CWAC's EndlessAdapter

Tags: android, listview, endlessadapter

I'm using CWAC's Endlessadapter. By default it uses default ListView with just one TextView. I would like to use getView method in the adapter to set my item in the way I like such as:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


      viewHolder cell = null;
//      ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        if (convertView == null) {

            cell = new viewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,
                    parent, false);


            cell.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image_video);

            cell.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_video);

            cell.user = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.user_video);


            convertView.setTag(cell);
        } else {
            cell = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        imageLoader.displayImage(video.mostviewedvideos.get(position).small_poster, cell.image);
        cell.title.setText(video.categoryvideos.get(position).title); 

        cell.user.setText(video.categoryvideos.get(position).username); 







        return convertView;

    }

    static class viewHolder {

        TextView title;
        TextView user;
        ImageView image;
    }
```

When I add `getView()` in my `EndlessAdapter`, `getPendingView()` doesn't work anymore. Just wonder how can I make this work.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm answer my own question. All we need is just to super my `CustomAdapter` in the `EndlessAdapter`:

```
public EndlessAdapter(Context mContext) {
    super(new CustomAdapter(mContext));
...
}
```